# Function not writing nodes to tree when using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, nodes

I am a student who is making a tree structure in cpp for a project. The program is supposed to get a string from an input and enter it into a tree. The tree is organized by each node having the pointer to its next sibling (called sibling) and its first child (called child). However, when I try to make a function that recursively adds members to the tree, the function doesn't work. All of the neccisarry steps are completed, yet for some reason the nodes are not linked. Please take a look at my code, and thank you for reading.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
struct node{
    char data;
    node *sibling = nullptr;
    node *child = nullptr;
};
struct node* newNode(char data, unsigned int m)
{
    if(m!=0) {
        struct node *node = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        // std::cout << "node write" << std::endl;

        node->data = data;
        node->sibling = newNode(124,m-1);
        node->child = newNode(124,m-1);
        return (node);
    }
}
char TreeOutput(node *n){
    return *(char *)n;
}

void nodeAdd(node *currentNode, std::string str, int m ){
    int n = str.length();
    if(m<n){
        if(TreeOutput(currentNode) == str[m]){
            std::cout << m << "1..1" << std::endl;

            nodeAdd(currentNode->child,str,m+1);
        }
        else if(TreeOutput(currentNode) == 124){
            std::cout << m <<  "2..2" << std::endl;

            currentNode = newNode(str[m],2);
            nodeAdd(currentNode->child,str,m+1);
        }
        else{
            std::cout << m << "3..3" << std::endl;

            nodeAdd(currentNode->sibling,str,m+1);
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    struct node *root = newNode('X',6);
    std::cout << root->data << std::endl;

    nodeAdd(root->child,"APE",0);
    std::cout << root << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is more c question then c++ one. In c++ you usually use classes and not structures.

Comment: I am not too familiar with classes, but how could they be used to improve this program?

Comment: @Jayylmao  structs and classes in c++ are exactly the same except for their default access.  Classes are private by default, structs are public.  I exclusively use structs just for this reason.

Comment: @SeanMcAllister you can use always "public", if you want to, but it's not an OOP thinking. OOP gives you the option to give different access privillage to every object in your code for a reason, to help you use the right way with your code. You right, you can add functions to structs in c++, but still all of them are accessible to all of the objects in the code. One more thing, in classes all the default functions are exists, and in structs they are not.

Comment: Overall, it's certainly written much more in C style than in C++ style, but that hasn't much to do with `struct`s vs. `class`es.  Nevertheless, many of the details are specific to C++; no conforming C compiler would accept it.  Inasmuch as C and C++ have differing syntax and semantics in several areas, then, this can only be interpreted as a C++ question.

Comment: @KorelK I think you're mistaken about default functions (assuming you mean copy constructor, etc), they get generated the same way for structs, there really is no difference except the default visibility.  I make things private as appropriate, but generally the first thing I do in a class is public: to define the public API, so I use structs to avoid that.  It also allows public inheritance by default too, just less typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason they're not getting linked in this line:

```
currentNode = newNode(str[m],2);
```

Is because you're taking a node* to the function, then assigning *the pointer inside the function* a new value.  So you change currentNode's value inside the function, but not in its parent.  You need to take either a reference to the pointer or a double pointer for this to work correctly:

```
void nodeAdd(node*& currentNode, std::string str, int m )
```

It might make more sense if we remove the syntactic sugar for pointers.  Imagine a pointer to node was written `Ptr<node>`, if we wrote:

```
void nodeAdd(Ptr<node> currentNode, std::string str, int m )
```

It's be obvious we're taking the *pointer* by value, so it now lives in a variable within the function.  If we take it by reference, we can change its value outside the function:

```
void nodeAdd(Ptr<node>& currentNode, std::string str, int m )
```

Tangentially, you have char data in your node struct, I think you want a pointer there too (or an array).

In terms of general style, if you're trying to write C++, usually the contents of newNode would go in a constructor so you could just write `new node(args...)` to create a new instance.  The TreeOutput function will work *in this case* because of the simple layout of node, but in general, casting to the first member of a struct doesn't have to work (in particular in the case of inheritance or virtual methods), so I'd at the very least access the member directly `return node->data;`